# comparison: is "faster than I thought" correct?

Tags: comparison, comparative

In a grammar book I find this question:

Find the mistake

> The car run faster than I thought.

Does this sentence have a grammar mistake? I guess not.

Edit: I thought "run" is in the simple past tense so I could not find any mistake in the verb.

Comment: There are many websites where you can learn to conjugate common English verbs, e.g. **[this one.](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/run)** You should bookmark them!

Answer (score 7):

The issue is with the verb, "run."

Since "car" is singular, the verb should be "runs." If we had a plural subject, then we'd say "run."

> The *car runs* faster than I thought.
>   The *cars run* faster than I thought.

Note, though, that we can also say "run" with a singular, first person subject:

> *I run*.

"Faster than I thought" is perfectly acceptable English, though.

Comment: Or perhaps, "The car ran faster than I thought."

Comment: You might also mention that the sentence _"The car runs faster than I thought"_ is an elision of "it would": _"The car runs faster than I thought [it would]."_

Comment: @AstPace I'd expect Past Perfect then, "**The car ran faster than I had though**" if speaking deeper into the past.